# The sum of three primes is 100, one of them exceeds the other by 36, find the largest one

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> The sum of $3$ primes numbers is $100$. One of them exceeds the other by $36$. Find the largest one.

My attempts:

Let $p_1 +p_2  + p_3=100$, also let $p_2=p_1 +36 \implies 2p_1 +p_3=64$, from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148924/sum-of-three-primes) $p_1 \neq p_2 \neq2 \implies p_3=2$, hence $p_1 =31 \implies p_2=67$.

Is this make sense, I don't have an answer, please add your answer.

Comment: It looks fine, so +1.

Comment: Actually, how'd you conclude $p_1\ne2$?  That step is slightly missing.

Comment: @SimpleArt then $p_2$ won't be prime.

Comment: Ok, then everything looks good :-)

Comment: If three primes sum to an even number, then at least one of the primes is 2.

Comment: Yes your answer is correct @Ayushakj.

Comment: One of the primes has to be $2$. Hence the question is: Two numbers add up to $98$, and their difference is $36$. Not much number theory at stake here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of three primes](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148924/sum-of-three-primes)

Answer (score 3):

As we know that the sum of three odd numbers cannot be even i.e. one of the prime is even or $2$ let one of the other prime is $p_1$ then the third prime is $p_1+36$ now according to question $$2+p_1+p_1+36=100$$ $$2p_1=62$$ $$p_1=31$$ Hence, the primes are

> $$2,31,67$$

Answer (score 0):

You found correctly that $2p_1+p_3=64$ then you obtain that $p_3$ is even then $p_3=2$ and consequently $p_1=31$. Therefore the result you found was correct.

Answer (score 0):

I start with @Guangliang, that one of the primes must be $2$.  Then the other two sum to $98$ and differ by $36$.  Solving the simultaneous equations gives $31$ and $67$.